# Cannot login after ctrl+alt+F1

Tags: shortcut-keys, login, login-screen

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (while I was logged in) and got the console interface.

After logging in, I wanted to go back to GUI, so I typed `startx`. It didn't work, so I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and logged in and out a couple of times, and repeated the process, after which I typed `sudo reboot` to reboot computer.

After that, Ubuntu booted normally, but when I try to log into my account, it just returns me back to the login screen. I entered the console intreface again, tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, but in vain. Logging in into other accounts including the guest account is successful, but I cannot log into my account.

Fortunately, I have cloned the entire HDD about a month ago, so should I restore the backup, or is there a quick solution? I'm not willing to do some advanced programming or so, because it would take much less effort to install some missing updates and some programs after the restore than to mend my system and make it unstable, if it's seriously broken. I also have all my data backed up on spideroak, so it's not a problem too. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way to *go back* to your X environment is to go to the *tty* it's running on, usually 5 or 7.

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

Or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Alternatively, you can cycle through your *tty* with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.